# Intelij idea Hashmaps print to console

Tags: java, intellij-idea, hashmap, console-application

I'm trying to print data from 2 hashmaps to console, but I noticed that only one is depicted there. Here is a code sample:

```
public class HashMapsmathces {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Map<String, Object> hm1 = new HashMap<>();

    hm1.put("id", 1);
    hm1.put("sku","qazwsx");
    hm1.put("price", 11);

    printMaps(hm1);

    Map<String, Object> hm2 = new HashMap<>();

    hm1.put("id", 2);
    hm1.put("sku","qazwsx");
    hm1.put("price", 13);

    printMaps(hm2);
}

public static void printMaps(Map<String, Object> map)
{

    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> pair : map.entrySet())
    {
        String key = pair.getKey();
        String value = pair.getValue().toString();
        System.out.println(key + " : " + value);
    }
    }
}
```

So, when I press "Run" only `hm1` will be pushed to console. I'm not quite sure why.

Here a screenshot as well
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ok6h.png)

Thanks.

Comment: Thats because hm2 is empty, you are reassigning values to hm1 after declaration of hm2 map. Pfb the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are indeed printing both maps.  However `hm2` is empty.  (You're only ever adding to `hm1`.)

Comment: Joe, Thanks.
I didn't notice that typo. Probably I should double check a code, before asking such questions.

Comment: Spending some time in a debugger would also be useful before coming to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 4):

Thats because hm2 is empty, you are reassigning values to hm1 after declaration of hm2 map.

```
public class HashMapsmathces {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Map<String, Object> hm1 = new HashMap<>();

    hm1.put("id", 1);
    hm1.put("sku","qazwsx");
    hm1.put("price", 11);

    printMaps(hm1);

    Map<String, Object> hm2 = new HashMap<>();

    hm2.put("id", 2);
    hm2.put("sku","qazwsx");
    hm2.put("price", 13);

    printMaps(hm2);
}

public static void printMaps(Map<String, Object> map)
{
    //напишите тут ваш код
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> pair : map.entrySet())
    {
        String key = pair.getKey();
        String value = pair.getValue().toString();
        System.out.println(key + " : " + value);
    }
    }
}
```